# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 unknown column "user_id" in foreign key definition

Tags: sql, database, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have this error when i run :

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1 unknown column "user_id" in foreign key definition (SQL:
>   create table "users" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement,
>   "name" varchar not null, "email" varchar not null, "username" varchar
>   not null, "email_verified_at" datetime null, "password" varchar not
>   null, "remember_token" varchar null, "created_at" datetime null,
>   "updated_at" datetime null, foreign key("user_id") references
>   "users"("id") on delete cascade))

I'm following a video tutorial on youtube, and the code of the tutorial is this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

If I copy and paste this code I have the error. So i searched on stackoverflow and I've found this solution:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');             
        });

        Schema::table('profiles', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
```

This is my users table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

But today, when i run `php artisan migrate:fresh` I had this error again.

How can I solve?

Thanks

Comment: delete the table and rerun the migration again!

Comment: where is your `users` table migration

Comment: you should check your migrations orders. "users" table creation must run before "profiles" table creation.

Comment: @spyker i'm editing with the users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `user_id` isn't a column in your `users` table, but you are trying to create an index on it.  This line:

```php
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

belongs in the `profiles` table creation schema and not in the `users` table creation schema.

The full code:

```php
// create_users_table.php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

// create_profiles_table.php   <-- migrate AFTER users table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('url')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly mention here:

```
foreign key("user_id") references "users"("id") on delete cascade)
```

and you don't have a column with name `user_id`

The syntax is:

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name (columns)  <-- this must be a column in the table
REFERENCES parent_table(columns)
ON DELETE action
ON UPDATE action
```

but in your case `user_id` column is not available in the query. So either add the that column or remove this constraint code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is that the profile table was created before the user table.
I have a trick for problem solve.

**You should  rename migration files in the migration directory.**

for example let my file names be like this

- 2019_06_10_000001_create_users_table.php
- 2019_06_10_000002_create_profiles_table.php

first user table is created when you run "artisan migrate or migrate:fresh"

why? because first created migration file is user file.You should look carefully

- 2019_06_10_000001 -> users table name
- 2019_06_10_000002 -> profiles table name

**Solution:**
So u just need to do this: rename "user" table and name it numerically smaller than the "profiles" table.So problem will solve.

**Other solution:**
delete all migration files after run them respectively this commands.

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
php artisan make:migration create_profiles_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('url')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->index('user_id');             
    });
}
```

That is the migration. Before you are able to run it; delete the row for 'CreateProfilesTable' in the migrations table.